# how to generate "reply to" link from "mail to" string in c#

Tags: c#, html, html-email

I want `reply to` link similar to `mail to`.
I generate email string from c# code and want to put `reply to` link which replies to current email. Can anyone help to put `reply to` link in c# code?
`for example:` to generate mailto link we use `mailto:testemail@gmail.com?subject=testsubject`.
By clicking on this link, we are able to mail to particular emailid.
Similarly, I want reply to link by clicking on it, user is able to generate email as reply to current email.

Comment: Are you describing the Html link "mailto" ? Please post some sample code showing how far you have got in solving the problem and where your particualar issue is.

Comment: @PhillipH , thanks for your reply. I put example here as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are showing your user an existing email which they are trying to reply to ? There is no HTML tag that does this.

You haven't said where this email is coming from, but I assume you are showing your user an email or other communication that is generated in your system. If this is the case they you will need to code this up just like any other POST link and pass in the "id" of the email you want to reply to - the result of the POST should be a redirect to an email-like page where you have programmatically filled out much of the email content by quoting it from the original email.

Once the user has filled out this Reply mail page, another HTTP POST back to your server and you can use the .net SMTP capability to construct an actual email and send it from your server. Note that there is no capability of sending such and email from your users mail account, or using their mail client.